# Sequential counter for repeating counting sequence

Tags: flipflop, counter, state-machines, ripple-counter, sequence-detector

I'm aware of designing synchronous counter design for a counting sequence where I write the state table with present and next state and then followed by flip flop inputs (filled using the excitation table of the corresponding flip flop). But how to design if the states are repeating I'm not aware on how to proceed further and hence needed help.how to design a synchronous counter for a repeating counting sequence.  I have listed an example .[image]

Comment: Count up normally to the number of steps you want using a regular counter and then use another circuit to convert the count value to the output you want. Or if you were doing this with real chips instead of just gates feed the output of the counter to a ROM lookup table to output the values you want.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: I thought of FSM as well but then that would need extra inputs which is not allowed in counters.

Comment: Sorry 3, You are actually counting a sequence of 8 states. So you need 3 bits... = 3 flip-flops. The values 0,1,2 and 3 are taken from the 2nd and 3rd bit of the counter. You ignore the first "bit".

Comment: But then what if the counting sequence is something like 0-1-0-2-0-3?

Comment: @Fawaz - Then you convert the outputs of the first, third, and fifth states to zero. The internal representation of a state does not need to be your output.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 3.

You are actually counting a sequence of 8 states. So you need 3 bits... = 3 flip-flops.

The values 0,1,2 and 3 are taken from the 2nd and 3rd bit of the counter. You ignore the first "bit".

Or if you prefer, you can refer to the first stage as a clock divider "/2" for your two bit counter.

State machines can be simple or can get to be extremely complicated looping, input dependant beasts what give engineers nightmares.

In your simple examples you are actually asking for two different things.

First, to sequence through a pattern of N numbers then repeat. For that you need to count where you are in the sequence using your counter up to N. When N is reached you need logic to reset the counter.

Second you need logic to OUTPUT the appropriate value at each count.

If the latter is extremely complex or likely to change upon development and experimentation, it is usually done by feeding the count as an address into an E-Prom which is programmed to give out the right value on its data pins according to the counter value.

One of said data pins can be used to reset the counter so you can have a different N value, some can be used to feed back on itself as more address pins to switch pages.

As I say, it can get intricately complicated.

Comment: What I was looking for is a generalised method. What if the counting sequence is 0-1-0-2-0-3?

Comment: Then you would need some form of reset or pre-setting logic that sets the load condition state based on the current state. Without a micro the simplest way to do that is with an e-prom.

Comment: @Fawaz, if it has the same outputs but different next state (and no distinction on inputs) then you have to treat it as a different state. So your new example has 6 states.

Comment: It really depends on the sequence though. It does not need to get very complicated before you are better off using a programmable device.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm sorry I'm not able to understand, this being a counter problem and not FSM problem, I'm finding it difficult to understand about input and output.

Comment: @Fawax, input is the current state, output is the required next state given the current state. However the sequence 0,1,0,2,0,3 is not like that. the 2nd  and third zeros are DIFFERENT states, since they have different NEXT values. SO you need a counter that has six states, then use logic of some sort to generate the required output value from that count. Or a PROM.

Comment: @Fawaz, a counter is a kind of FSM.

Comment: @ThePhoton but doesn't FSM need need external inputs and in counters there aren't any external inputs and also the output in a counter is only the flip flop outputs or states but FSM has output which depends on only the states or both states and input. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm only an undergraduate student who is taking up this course.

Comment: No, inputs aren't required to make something an FSM. A counter is an FSM. With 0 inputs (or possibly with a reset input, maybe an up/down input, a pre-load input, etc), and with output that depends only on the state (with the output being equal to the internal representation of the state).

Comment: @Fawaz... State machines can be simple or can get extremely complicated looping, input dependant beasts what give engineers nightmares. In your simple examples you are asking for two different things. First, to sequence through a pattern of N numbers then repeat. For that you need to count where you are in the sequence using your counter up to N. Second you need logic to OUTPUT the appropriate value at each count.

Answer (score 0):

0,0 ,1,1 ,2,2 ,3,3 ,0,0...

Equivalent Binary rep:
00,00,01,01,10,10,11,11,00,00....

Sequence being repeated , we need to make then distinguish but using 1 bit additionally
000,100 , 001,101 , 010,110 , 011,111 , 000,100 ,....
Equivalent Decimal rep:
0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7,0,1.....

Having 8 states -> mod 8 counter
Min flip flop required will be -> 3 .